# Assembly can be linked when compiling with GCC but not with G++, why and how to fix?

Tags: gcc, g++

I always thought C++ was C with some libraries built on top. And I thought any C program could be compiled with g++, I seem to be wrong.

I have some assembly code that can be sumarized as

```
_start:
    b kernel_main
```

I then have some c code in main.

If I compile and link with gcc, everything works. If I try to compile the same code with G++ (absolutely no change, not even file extensions)
I get the error:

```
In function `_start':
(.init+0x4): undefined reference to `kernel_main'
```

So G++ couldn't find the kernel_main label. Upon further inspection (disassembling binaries) it seems that g++ changes the kernel_main label to be `_Z11kernel_mainv`. Is there any way to tell g++ to keep labels intact?

Comment: Have you heard about [*name mangling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) or seen `extern "C"` in C++ function declarations? My suggestion is that you read up about those.

Answer (score 0):

`g++` will treat inputs files (even with `.c` extension) as C++ and consequently mangle names of functions unless they have been marked with `extern "C"`. So `kernel_main` has turned into something like `_Z11kernel_mainv`.